# I am fetching image from camera but its not uploading on firebase but with same method when I choose image from gallery its working

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am getting an image from gallery, uploading it to firebase and its working, but when I upload an image from camera it doesn't upload the same filepath I passed through. When using camera the filepath is showing null

```
 if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != 
 null) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
 //            filePath = getImageUri(this, bitmap);
        camIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICTURE) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        Log.e("filePath", "onActivityResult: " + filePath);
        try {
            bitmap = 
   MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), filePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) 
  (bitmap.getWidth() / 4), (int) (bitmap.getHeight() / 4), true);
        camIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        Log.e("imageFromGallery", "onActivityResult: " + bitmap);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed  to get data", 
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

It directly goes to the else part where I toast bitmap is null(only if I 
am using camera option) using gallery option it works fine.

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and show how you are building the `Intent` that leads to the `startActivityForResult()` call for `CAMERA_REQUEST`.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST); this is how i am opening camera

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your `if` line and see what the values are for `requestCode`, `resultCode`, and `data`.

Comment: the problem is this filepath giving me null i cant understand why

Comment: if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();
            bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");}
            startShareMediaActivity();

Comment: "the problem is this filepath giving me null i cant understand why" -- it is supposed to be `null`. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is not supposed to return a `Uri`. Your photo is in your `Bitmap`.

Comment: i am capturing image and set it to imageview its works fine but the problem is my image is in bitmap and i have to pass uri  and i tried multiple option to concvert bitmap to uri but it didnot worked for me

Comment: Save the bitmap to a file using `compress()`. Make the image file available to other apps via `FileProvider`.